# Imaginary number vector rotation 60 degrees

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors

With which complex number can I rotate a vector 60 degrees clockwise?

I do not know where to begin I tried using the unit circle but I keep getting confused. Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you representing vectors as complex numbers?

Comment: Do you know unitary complex numbers as $e^{i\theta}$?

Comment: Hints: do you know Euler's formula for $e^{it}$? Do you know how to multiply complex numbers when you have expressed them in polar coordinates?

Comment: I know hot to multiply complex numbers, I am trying to understand how you rotate a vector 60 degrees clockwise

Comment: Do you know how to multiply complex numbers *when they are expressed in polar coordinates*?

Comment: $$e^{i\pi\over 3}=\cos{\pi\over 3}+i\sin{\pi\over 3}={1\over 2}+i{\sqrt{3}\over 2}$$

Comment: the complex number 0,5 + 0.86i is that the answer to rotate the vector? I used the calculator and sin 60 and I got 0.5 which is exactly on the unit circle. I did the same with cos 60 and got 0.86. but to make a 60 degrees rotation i have to use 300 degrees or not?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, in the polar form. A complex number is written as $z = \rho \cdot e^{j\phi}$ with $\rho$ the absolute value and $\phi$ the argument.

A multiplication would be $z_1 \cdot z_2 = \rho_1 \rho_2 e^{j(\phi_1 + \phi_2)}$
Knowing that, by using $z_2 = e^{j\phi_2}$ we can rotate any $z_1$ on a $\phi_2$ degrees.
Note that $\rho_2 = 1$ to avoid changing the amplitude.

Finally, if you like the cartesian form notation, $z_2 = e^{j\phi_2} = cos(\phi_2) + j sen(\phi_2)$ would be your complex value.